# In Zoom’s Web SDK, is Zoom.generateSignature development only?

Tags: zoom-sdk

I’m looking to implement the Zoom Web SDK into my React apps and wondering what’s the correct way to generate a signature.

From some examples, I see that it should be a new endpoint to generate one.

However [when looking at this example](https://github.com/michaeldharrington/react-zoomus-websdk/blob/master/src/Zoom.js#L33), it seems like `ZoomMtg` exposes a `generateSignature` method. It *does* say to use this in development only, but I’m just wondering what would be the correct way to implement this. Should it be a separate service? Or could I rely on this to generate a signature on a production app?

Answer (score 0):

Zoom Developer Advocate here.

The correct way to generate the [Meeting SDK](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/) and [Video SDK](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/auth/) signature is on the server side. This will ensure your SDK Secret is not exposed on the client side if you were to deploy your code.

The flow looks like this:

1. On the client side, make an HTTP Request to your server side.
2. On the server side, generate the signature and return it to the client side.
3. On the client side, pass the signature into the SDK join function.

Here is a client side sample app for the [Meeting SDK](https://github.com/zoom/meetingsdk-javascript-sample/blob/master/client-view.js) that demonstrates the HTTP request to fetch the signature.

Here is a server side sample app for easily and securely generating the [Meeting SDK](https://github.com/zoom/meetingsdk-auth-endpoint-sample) and [Video SDK](https://github.com/zoom/videosdk-auth-endpoint-sample) signature.

For questions specific to the Zoom Developer Platform, feel free to ask on the [Zoom devforum](https://devforum.zoom.us/).